# Workgroup computer inaccessible on the network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I’m having an issue with a computer that is inaccessible to the rest of the workgroup. This workstation has its file sharing enabled in Network and Sharing Center and can be pinged on the network by other computers (as well as ping out.) There are three computers in a workgroup including the computer in question and all other computers are working correctly. I have a shared folder on the inaccessible computer and have given ‘Everyone’ read access.

Trying to navigate to \\dns-name doesn’t work nor does \\ip-address.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the computer is visible in explorer or is visible but inaccessible?

Comment: The computer is listed under Network in Explorer.

Comment: Compare credentials at all three computers at `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`. Look for difference

Comment: They are all using the Homegroup$ account with credentials set by the wizard when joining the Homegroup. I changed the account to the local user in credential manager but it doesn’t work either. I do not believe this to be a credential issue.